# fetching user id from login SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, oop, session, mysqli

I have recently switched my code from mysql to mysqli OOP for better practice.  I am trying to fetch the `user_id` from my mysql table and save it in `$_SESSION['user_id']`. I have tried many different iterations of my code and worked on it for hours but no luck.  As of now `$_SESSION['user_id']` returns nothing.  It works with my old mysql code so I know its not an issue with my table.  I am still new at mysqli and I would greatly appreciate any help in this matter.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","pw","db"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tapp_login WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
  $username = $_POST['user_name'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

  $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
  $stmt->store_result();
  if($stmt->num_rows == 1){ //To check if the row exists
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ //fetching the contents of the row
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[1];
      $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;
      $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;            
      echo 'true';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo 'false';
  }
  $stmt->free_result();
  $stmt->close();
}
else{
}
$con->close();

?>
```

The validation works and the user name is successfully stored in the session.  I think the error is in the `$row = $stmt->fetch()` but I cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: I have an AJax that requires an echo 'true' result. When I tried to put the var_dump($row); inside the while loop my validation no longer works. So if I do the same on a printed version of the row variable outside the loop I get a "NULL"..  I not sure if that is a good or even correct method.

Comment: When debugging Ajax, you can just make a direct call to the script with your browser, then you can review the results.

Comment: An alternate method is to use Firefox with Firebug and examine the output from the server. Any echo, exit, print_r or var_dump that you use will be viewable in the Firebug console window.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is this line:

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[1];

I believe it should either be $row[0] or $row['user_id'].

(note: I used 'user_id', but it would be the name of the column that holds the IDs)

Comment: Also, it is bad practice to use '*' to get 1 column from a row. You should just use the column name.

Comment: I see. Well, the next obvious issue would be that your WHERE is not netting any results. You can do what Kingkero said, use var_dump($row) to see what is there. You could also finish your if($stmt->num_rows == 1) with an else{ exit('no record found'); } to check that you are getting results.

Comment: Also, in the future, please post any attempts you have already made to resolve your issue.

Comment: I just noticed you have '$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);', You should be able to change this to '....->bind_result($user_id). Then use $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id. bind_results take the results from each row and dumps them into the corresponding variable in the parenthesis.

Comment: I am selecting your answer because your comments worked for me. I changed the '*' to specific columns and I also had to use `$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $password);`. Thank you Lee!